# In Swift what does Element mean when writing an extension on Array?

Tags: swift

What does Element mean when writing an extension on Array?

like in this example:

```
extension Array {
    func reduce<T>(_ initial: T, combine: (T, Element) -> T) -> T {
        var result = initial
        for x in self {
            result = combine(result, x)
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: To help you understand it, you can think it as `Array`, being in fact `[Element]`. It's a way to represent what's the type of the elements that are inside the array.

Comment: so element is essentially a single item in array of the array type?

Comment: Yes. You can see it `@frozen struct Array<Element>` and `Arrays are one of the most commonly used data types in an app. You use arrays to organize your app’s data. Specifically, you use the Array type to hold elements of a single type, the array’s Element type. An array can store any kind of elements—from integers to strings to classes.` on doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array

Comment: More accurately, it is the _type_ of the elements in the array, not the items themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combine parameter is a function which takes a parameter of type `T` and `Element`. The Element is the actual Element of/in the array.

For example, this is an array of `Int` elements:

```
let arr = [1,2,5,77]
```

In reduce, initial is of type `T`. This is the staring value for the mapping you are about to perform.
In combine, `T` is like your starting value for **each subsequent** step of combing the next Element to produce another value of type `T` which will be used as the next `T` in combine, and so and so forth until the entire array has been processed.

If you were using a default use of reduce such as:

```
arr.reduce(0, +)
```

You can see that in this case, `T` and `Element` would both be of the same type, `Int`.

However, I could have a custom object that the array is of, and my combine is defining how to get the running total. If you had something like this:

```
struct Thing {
   var val1: String
   var val2: Int
}

let thingArray = //...define some Things in an array
```

You could use reduce and define your own combine function to return the sum of all the val2 values. In this case, `T` would be an `Int`, and `Element` would be Thing.

Comment: Thank you.  Could could explain what this function does using the above extension.  

func sumUsingReduce(integers: [Int]) -> Int {
    return integers.reduce(0) { result, x in result + x}
}